# How does one use Javascript to select a value from a drop down list and pass that value as a var to another function?

Tags: javascript

I know this is simple, but I can't get it working. I'm hoping someone here can help.

First off, this is part of a web app for iOS.

Okay, I have a list of items:

```
Room Type: <select id="isoList" name="isoList">
<option></option>
<option value="20">ISO 8 Life Sciences Low Use</option>
<option value="25">ISO 8 Life Sciences Med Use</option>
<option value="30">ISO 8 Life Sciences High Use</option>
</select>
```

I need to have the user select the room type, then pass the option value - as a var - to another function that uses the var in a calculation.

Here's the script I have to far. My form is named airflow...

```
function isoChange()
{
var isoChange = document.airflow("isoList");
var airChanges = isoChange.options[isoList.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Now I want to pass airChanges to this function...

```
function calcAF(airChanges)
{
var length = document.airflow.length.value; //length
var width = document.airflow.width.value; //width
var height = document.airflow.height.value; //height
var changes = airChanges; // hourly air changes
}
```

From there the calcAF function will use the var in various math formulae.

I've got it to work if I get the user to tell me airChanges, but it breaks when I try to get the airChanges from a drop down list.

Comment: What is `airflow`? If it's a library, I have not heard of it.

Comment: Hi Matt. airflow is that the form that uses this drop down is named.

Comment: :) Matt, it happens to me all the time.

Comment: Thank you all who helped. I ended up moving the isoChange() code into the calcAF() and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the problem, but from what I understand, the `isoChange` function should look like this:

```
function isoChange()
{
   var isoChange = document.airflow("isoList");
   var airChanges = isoChange.options[isoList.selectedIndex].value;
   calcAF(airChanges);
}
```

Comment: Can you alert the value and make sure that isn't the issue.

Comment: Sorry jd, alert the value? I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: Hi jd, I did the alert and it comes back undefined.

Comment: Do you mean `document.airflow["isoList"]` instead of `document.airflow("isoList")`?

Comment: Thanks JD, I moved the code to the calcAF() and it now works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The *onchange* event of a <select> element will be triggered every time the selection changes

```
document.getElementById('isoList').onchange = function() { 
    calcAF(this.value);
}​
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hba9a/5/

Comment: Thanks Lost, I've tried that method, but cannot get it to pass the variable to my calcAF function. I don't need it to show onscreen what the value is, I need the value to be translated into a variable I can use in calcAF to so some math. For example: 'var freq = (60/changes*1));' to find out the frequency in minutes.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your calcAF function. Remove everything from the function and just add alert(airChanges); if that works, then you can be sure that calcAF is malfunctioning

Comment: Thanks Lost, I get 'undefined' in the alert. everything cleared out of  calcAF. my isoChange should look like this? - function isoChange()
{
var airChanges = document.getElementById('isoList').onchange = function() {
 calcAF(this.value);
 }
  }

Comment: no, do not put the code I suggested in your function, put it outside of your function.. you no longer need the isoChange function. Look at the jsfiddle, and understand what's going on

Comment: I tried taking the code out of a function and still get undefined. I now also get an error in my web inspector (on Safari) "null" is not an object for the line number the code is on. jsfiddle is great, just not working for what I need. Do I need to loop through the options maybe?

Comment: Lost, thank you for your help. I'll certainly use this snippet in the future!